# Powershell: need assistance with output if item is not found

Tags: powershell

I have a script that searches a csv file and returns a Payrol Dept Number based on a user inputting the employee First and Last name. I want to be able to tell the user that no name matches their query if the First and Last name does not return a result. I've tried different if/else statements but have not gotten it to work. Here is what I have:

```
$csv = import-csv c:\employees.csv
$First = read-host 'What is the users first name?'
$Last = read-host 'What is the users last name?'
$csv | Where-Object { $_.last -eq $Last -and $_.'First Name' -eq $First } |
Select-Object -Expand 'Payroll Department Number'
```

Comment: If a user is not found, I want this to run: write-host "User does not exist"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the result from `Where-Object` to a variable and check if it's empty. Ex:

```
$csv = import-csv c:\employees.csv
$First = read-host 'What is the users first name?'
$Last = read-host 'What is the users last name?'
$res = $csv | Where-Object { $_.last -eq $Last -and $_.'First Name' -eq $First }

if($res) { $res | Select-Object -Expand 'Payroll Department Number' }
else { Write-Host "User does not exist" }
```